# How to display entire subject line in `mail`?

Tags: command-line, mailx

There are two messages in `/var/mail/test`.

```
mail
Mail version 8.1.2 01/15/2001.  Type ? for help.  
"/var/mail/test": 2 messages 2 new
>N  1 test@test      Tue Feb 17 15:07   18/628   *** SECURITY information fo
N  2 test@test      Tue Feb 17 15:25   18/628   *** SECURITY information fo
```

1. How to get the whole subject line of message 1 displayed in my console?
2. How to get the body of the message 1 displayed in my console?

Comment: 2. Press `Enter` on the active message (the one with the `>` next to it)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Linux command line syntax as

Read email if you have only email.
echo p|mail |grep -A 1 "^Subject:"
Read 1st email, change the number you want to read email.
echo 'type 1'|mail |grep -A 1 "^Subject:"